# Created AWS EC2 instance from snapshot AMI, eth0 is missing after startup

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ethernet

I recently created a new EC2 from a snapshot of our Production EC2.

The machine started up fine, and I can ssh in, however - cannot access via anything else. No WWW, nothing.

Upon further inspection of the device, primarily the network stack - I see this:

*/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules*

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="06:68:f3:22:91:f2", NAME="ens5"
```

*ifconfig*

```
ens5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 172.31.12.146  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.31.15.255
        inet6 fe80::468:f3ff:fe22:91f2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 06:68:f3:22:91:f2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 492  bytes 81928 (80.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 474  bytes 76982 (75.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6  bytes 416 (416.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6  bytes 416 (416.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Note the **ens5** at the first line of the `ifconfig`.

*[/etc] # service network restart*

```
Restarting network (via systemctl):  Job for network.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status network.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                       [FAILED]
```

*[/etc] # systemctl status network.service*

```
● network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-10-16 11:13:34 EDT; 1min 4s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2223 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/network.service
           └─857 /sbin/dhclient -1 -q -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient--ens5.lease -pf /var/run/dhclient-ens5.pid -H ip-172-31-12-146 ens5

Oct 16 11:13:34 ip-172-31-12-146.us-west-1.compute.internal network[2223]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 16 11:13:34 ip-172-31-12-146.us-west-1.compute.internal network[2223]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 16 11:13:34 ip-172-31-12-146.us-west-1.compute.internal network[2223]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 16 11:13:34 ip-172-31-12-146.us-west-1.compute.internal network[2223]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 16 11:13:34 ip-172-31-12-146.us-west-1.compute.internal network[2223]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 16 11:13:34 ip-172-31-12-146.us-west-1.compute.internal network[2223]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 16 11:13:34 ip-172-31-12-146.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 16 11:13:34 ip-172-31-12-146.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Oct 16 11:13:34 ip-172-31-12-146.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state.
Oct 16 11:13:34 ip-172-31-12-146.us-west-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: network.service failed.
```

It cannot find eth0, nor can it restart the network stack. I have tried rebooting the machine, shutting down and starting up, with no luck. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you change from older instance type to T3 / M5 / C5? These have got a *different hardware* and use different device names.

One option is to *reconfigure the network stack* to reflect the new device names - that may be quite an undertaking unless you’re a skilled Linux admin and know what you are doing.

Or, easier, **change the instance type** to the same that you made the snapshot from. That should fix the device names back to what they used to be.

You can change the size, e.g. from *large* to *medium*, but keep the type - if it was T2 use T2 again.

Also I suggest you restore it from the snapshot to a fresh instance - the current one has probably tried to accommodate the new device names and may be in inconsistent state. Better to start again from the Prod snapshot.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This problem also happens with the default centos7 ami

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the device name in the udev rule you posted. Edit that line and rename `ens5` to `eth0`

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="06:68:f3:22:91:f2", NAME="eth0"
```

Comment: i did try that, and it did rename it, however - i still had no connectivity to the server?

Comment: Ah sorry, did you reboot the server? Or restart udev at least? If this doesn't work, you can possibly try setting an alias for the interface name. This post may help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391535/how-to-add-an-alternative-name-for-the-interface